# design pattern to get rid of flags/enums in a multithreaded environment

Tags: java, design-patterns, coding-style

Original program code to modify:

/*this method is called periodically and it takes data from db, performs some ooperations on it, and puts the results in a file which is sent at the ends of all processing via ftp*/

```
void pullData(){
    while(!stopped){
        rows= getRowsFromDb();

        for (row: rows){
            newRow= process(row);
            rowsContainer.add(newRow)
        }

        writeToFile(rowsContainer);
        sendFileSomewhere();
    }
}
```

Now this code has to be modified to allow the following commands to be issued to it: process only 1 row; skip 1 row (more commands to come later). To do this the application is put in suspended mode and it will not process rows until it get one of the 2 commands I outlined above. Also, it can be resumed from suspended mode and then it's back to normal processing.

The question is not how to do this, but what is the right way to do it.

(1) Someone suggested boolean flags for each operation. This is a pretty bad idea. I recommend people avoid flags for many reasons (some may have been discussed on stack overflow as well).

(2) Another idea was to use a bool flag for isSuspended and enums for the commands. This is better than (1), but not a lot because app needs to check which command was the last one and if it is in suspended mode and act accoringly.

(3) I was thinking of breaking up the application and use the Strategy pattern. Each command would get it's own method in the application. This is a bit more complicated, but to me it seems a lot cleaner.

**What would you suggest (you don't need to choose from the options I listed, I want to hear how you handled a similar situation)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) with tasks like

```
private Future lastTask = null;

// only run one task at a time.
if (lastTask != null) lastTask.cancel(true);

lastTask = executorService.submit(new ProcessOnRowRunnable());
// or
lastTask = executorService.submit(new ProcessPendingRowsAndStopRunnable());
// or
lastTask = executorService.submit(new ProcessAllRowsUntilCancelledRunnable())

// later
future.cancel(true);
```

Note: Your loops have to honour interrupts or they won't stop just because the thread has been interrupted.  You can use

```
while(conditions && !Thread.curentThread().isInterrupted()) {
     // do work
}
```

Comment: This is very clean and it uses frameworks. I like it. One drawback is that if ProcessPendingRowsAndStopRunnable() is running, and then user issues ProcessOnRowRunnable(), the first task needs to be cancelled. It's acceptable. Thanks

Comment: It will work just fine even if they don't cancel, it just won't change it's behaviour. You can cancel the last task by default if wish.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need a message-passing ITC:

```
while true
  msg = getMsgFromQueue
  case msg 
    skipARow: skip();
    processARow: process();
    doSomethingElse:
```

Comment: This is nice. It's similar to what I was suggesting in (3). Thanks

Comment: It is message-passing ITC and has nothing to do with the strategy pattern. If you mean that you want to do row skipping while processing the loop, then getMsg() must be non-blocking. You just continue processing when no command is received. But, I do not understand how do you synchronize to skip exact row. If another thread commands such free-running thing to skip something, an arbitrary row will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this many time before using a Finite State Machine (or a subset which is simply state driven based on enums) - the big benefit is that you can validate your FSM and keep something manageable that doesn't suffer from the *mass of flags problem*

Figure 3. Simple State Diagram: (from [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/07/java-secret-using-enum-to-build-state.html))

[image: Figure 3. Simple State Diagram]

I've personally used FSM managing the actions that can be applied to objects (in this case Orders), managing the parsing of RFC-822 email messages, controlling hardware;

a very simplistic but functional example of a state driven loop:

```
state = S_Starting;
while(state != S_Finished){

    switch (state){
        case S_Starting:
             // do something 
             state = S_Running;
             break;

        case S_Running
             rows= getRowsFromDb();

             for (row: rows){
                  newRow= process(row);
                  rowsContainer.add(newRow)
             }
             state = S_HandleReceipt;

             break;

         case S_HandleReceipt:
             writeToFile(rowsContainer);
             sendFileSomewhere();

         case S_Paused:
             if (some_other_test){
                 state = S_Running;
             }
             break;
    }
    if (some_test_for_finished) {
        state = S_Finished;
    } else if (some_test_for_pause) {
                  state = S_Paused;
    }
}
```

refs:

- [Using an enum to build a State machine](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/07/java-secret-using-enum-to-build-state.html) for quite a neat way to do this.
- [A Finite State Machine Supporting Concurrent States](http://today.java.net/article/2009/09/06/finite-state-machine-supporting-concurrent-states)

The C# Hierarchical State Machine [Stateless](http://code.google.com/p/stateless/) is sadly not yet ported to Java but an excellent tool - I've used it many times and it's great.

Comment: great links! Thanks, this is quite a different approach. I like the loose coupling achieved by having each enum do something specific to its role